# How to connect inner most nodes of left and right branch of binary tree at every level

Tags: algorithm, tree, language-agnostic

Consider the below tree.
Need an algorithm to connect inner most nodes of left and right branch of tree at every level.
Connect in the sense 2->link is Node 3 and 3->link is Node 2

Input tree

```
          1
        /  \
       2     3 
      / \    / \
     4   5  6   7
    /   /      /
   8   9      10 
      / \    / \
     11 12  13  14
```

Output tree

```
         1
        /  \
       2=====3 
      / \    / \
     4   5==6   7
    /   /      /
   8   9======10 
      / \    / \
     11 12==13  14
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you talk us through what you've tried so far, what seems to be working, and where you're getting stuck?

Comment: What should happen when there are 3 nodes on one level. For instance, when the upper node 4 has a left child? How would the connections be then?

Comment: If you do a breadth-first search, you can get all of the children at a particular level. From there, it's a simple matter of finding the inner two, and linking them. Assuming, of course, you solve the problem of what "inner two" means when there's an odd number of items.

Comment: What should happen when 2<>3 or 5<>6?

Comment: @templatetypedef 
i tried level order traversal and found horizontal distance from root for all nodes in a level. Then searched for  nodes with smallest positive distance and least negative distance. But his does not help if left branch crosses towards right branch at a level

Comment: @trincot i updated the diagram for you

Comment: @JimMischel by innnermost i meant the innermost of left branch and right branch. Left branch means anything that was derived from left of root and vice versa.

Comment: @alexherm there will be a bridge at every level between left branch and right branch of root node at every level

Answer (score 0):

Your level-order traversal idea is a good one. Imagine doing a level-order traversal of the left and right subtrees of the root, independently of one another. Then,

- the last node you visit at each level while scanning the left subtree is the rightmost node at each layer in the left subtree, and
- the first node you visit at each level while scanning the right subtree is the leftmost node at each layer in the right subtree.

You can then write down these nodes and wire them together to get your overall result.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python implementation of a bread-first search, which stops as soon as one of both subtrees has no more nodes:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def children(self):
        if self.left:
            yield self.left
        if self.right:
            yield self.right

    def innerpairs(self):
        def nextlevel(level):
            for node in level:
                yield from node.children()

        level = list(self.children())
        levelleft = level[:1]
        levelright = level[1:]
        while levelleft and levelright:
            yield levelleft[-1].value, levelright[0].value
            levelleft = list(nextlevel(levelleft))
            levelright = list(nextlevel(levelright))
```

With this class you can create the tree from the question as follows:

```py
# example tree:
tree = Node(1,
    Node(2,
        Node(4,
            Node(8)
        ),
        Node(5,
            Node(9,
                Node(11),
                Node(12)
            )
        )
    ),
    Node(3,
        Node(6),
        Node(7,
            Node(10,
                Node(13),
                Node(14)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Then get the inner pairs as follows:

```py
print(list(tree.innerpairs()))  # [(2, 3), (5, 6), (9, 10), (12, 13)]
```